# Is it possible to access the user ID of all types of votes in the stackexchange data dumps ?

Tags: support

I'm working on a project which aims at analyzing the social relations between users on stackexchange. Hence, I'm pretty interested in the user IDs of votes in each post.  Although the votes can be accessed in the data dumps released by stackexchange, User IDs are only visible for votes whose type are 'favorite'. I was wondering if it is possible to access the user ID of all types of votes. My research is for academy only and the user IDs will be hashed for privacy concern.

Comment: That would violate the entire anonymity of voting.

Answer (score 1):

No, Stack Exchange* does not link up/down votes to users in any publicly available information source. Because this is not public information.

---

*I'm not representing SE, just stating something well-known.